# getExternalFilesDirs() not updated in ApplicationContext upon SD card insertion in API 23 & above

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-context, android-sdcard

When app is running in foreground and insert an SD card, and try to retrieve the path by using

```
ctx.getExternalFilesDirs(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

where the context is sometime **Application** and **Activity** Context

*When using activity context, get the updated SD card path but when Application context  used, don't get the updated path*

It happens only on **API 23**  and **24**

> Workaround is to kill the app and re-start the app

Does any one know is it a Marshmallow bug?

**Note:** I see some created an issue in google 
[Issue 214247](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214247)

Comment: So you are hot swapping?

Answer (score 0):

use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` along with `Environment.getExternalStorageState()`

Type DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD is not listed as valid parameter for getExternalFilesDir(), please check documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks for the response but i tried to use the option you mentioned but `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` it return only primary storage path `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory: /storage/emulated/0` not the SD card path